# getting error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable while using send_mail in django?

Tags: python, django, smtp, digital-ocean

Settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'no-reply@domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Zealous4$'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

code

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('dymmy', 'Here is the message.', 'demo@gmail.com',
        ['dymmy@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

It works in my local environment but it's not working on my production server (Digital Ocean).

Comment: That's a networking problem and off-topic on SO.